# Is it possible to disabel all HTML-Elements of a Form during a transaction is running

Tags: html, forms, disable

e.g. buttons..

```
<body disabled>
```

does not work

Thank you

Comment: do you mean database tranasaction ?

Comment: you might want to make the whole form div invisible and display an animated gif that suggests the processing and reverse once you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will select all descendants of your `form` element. You can use any selector to get the desired set of elements and apply this script to disable them all.

```
<script >
var form_elem=document.querySelectorAll("form *");
for(var i of form_elem){
i.setAttribute("disabled", true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: removing works like this:
<script >
var form_elem=document.querySelectorAll("form *");
for(var i of form_elem){
i.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
</script>

Answer (score 1):

I would use javascript:

```
<script language='Javascript'>
document.getElementById("this_is_the_submitbutton").disabled = true;
</script>
```

Your submitbutton needs to have have the `id='this_is_the_submitbutton'`